# PyShark - get data from second http2 layer of packet

Tags: python, pyshark

I use the LiveCapture Feature of PyShark:
With

`packet.layers`

I can see all the layers of my packet

`[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <TLS Layer>, <HTTP2 Layer>, <HTTP2 Layer>, <_WS.COL Layer>, <DATA Layer>]`

Now I like to read the data from the second http2 layer. I can read the data with:

`packet.http2.data_data`

It gives me the data of the first element. But I want the data of the second http2 layer.

I tried to count the layers with:

`packet.http2[1].data_data`

but this doesnt work. Any help for this?